# Declare a variable in DB2

Tags: variables, db2

I am a total novice in DB2.  I am trying to help someone else out who is an SQL Novice.

What I am trying to do would look like this in SQL Server:

```
declare @MaxValue int
select @MaxValue = Max(ID_COLUMN) from MainTable 

insert into MainTable (ID_COLUMN, OTHER_STUFF)
select TEMP_ID + @MaxValue, MORE_OTHER_STUFF
from   TempTable
```

How can I do this in DB2?  (Bonus points if you can tell me a way to do this so that the inserted values into ID_COLUMN just keep counting from the current max.)

Note: I see a lot of examples saying you can declare a variable like this

```
DECLARE myvariable int;
```

but that is erroring out for us.  So if you use that syntax maybe you can comment on why that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work. look [Here](http://www.sqlpl-guide.com/DECLARE) are you sure that you aren't making a more perhiperal typo? perhaps in the start block of your proc.

sounds like you want an identity column to me something like this.

```
col3 INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                                     (START WITH 100, INCREMENT BY 5))
```

if you are coming from SQL Server/Sybase, one nice thing with DB2 identity column is that  they don't 'jump' like they do on the afore mentioned platforms.

If you need to know the last identity value generated, then you do something like  this

```
 VALUES IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() INTO :MY_LOCAL_VAR_FOR_IDENTITY
```

thus you could probably do you need to by doing the above two SQL statements and then returning the values

Answer (score 1):

Variables can be declared inside of a compound SQL block, which is signified via BEGIN ATOMIC.